# iOS7 CLLocationManager pauses updates and won't resume

Tags: ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have a chunk of code that I can run in iOS simulation and get continuous locations updates, but when I run it on an iPad it seems to stall after the third update.  I have tried to change the activityType to other or and set things that might be causing it to pause updates, but those didn't seem to help.  It's also not clear to my why it's stopping in real life and not in the simulation.

I did try stopping updates on every update followed by a startUpdates and this did seem to work, but that strikes me as a bad way to behave.  Does anyone have additional recommendations or experience with this kind of issue.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *myLocationManager;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    for (int locIndex = 0; locIndex < locations.count; locIndex++)
    {
        CLLocation *newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locIndex];
        NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
    CLLocationDistance  distance = 0;
    NSTimeInterval timeout = 1;

    [manager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance timeout:timeout];


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    CLLocationDistance  distance = 0;
    NSTimeInterval timeout = 1;

    [manager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance timeout:timeout];


    /* We received the new location */

    NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    //[self.myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    //[self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    /* Failed to receive user's location */
    NSLog(@"******************************************************");
    NSLog(@"************** FAILED TO RECEIVE LOCATION ************");
    NSLog(@"******************************************************");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
        //self.myLocationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        //self.myLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;

        [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        //self.myPeripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];



    } else {
        /* Location services are not enabled.
         Take appropriate action: for instance, prompt the
         user to enable the location services */
        NSLog(@"Location services are not enabled");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the iPad have a SIM card, i.e. does it have mobile data?

Answer (score 1):

Pausing is used when the user has forgotten taht the GPS is active. To prevent the GPS to drain the battery the gps is then stoped and newer turned on again, before the app is started again.

You should catch the pause call and ask the user if the location updates should continue or not.